# Design Surface in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are there any recommendations for a design surface (or design tool) that could be used by a designer (the dude/dudette with the black turtleneck) in the process of building an ASP.Net MVC application?

Such that once there is agreement on the structure of the Model, and the interactions required by the app, then the designer goes away and builds out the UI (V in MVC) using this design tool, while the developer goes away and builds out the code (M&C in MVC) using Visual Studio.

As I understand it now, this designer person would also need to use Visual Studio and build the Views using Razor (or other view engine) syntax, instead of having the ability to build the Views using a design surface with drag-drop layout and property settings and the like.

Comment: +1 for the dude/dudette turtleneck joke. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could ask them to give you a harcoded HTML for each view... then, you replace the harcoded data once you place it in Razor.

That is the beauty of Razor... it is very easy to pass from fixed HTML to a razor view.

Comment: I flagged this as the accepted answer, as I also see this as the way to go.  Sadly it is not very condusive to making changes to the design though...when the designer gives a new version of the HTML, the developer would have to re-insert ALL the same Razor bits from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Razor requires programming, and creating views is not an arbitrary task.  I'd let the designer work in whatever program they like where they can excel about design and let the programmers worry about how best to create the views and programming in Razor (which is really just C#/VB with some extra syntax).

Answer (score 0):

It depends.. what kind of skills does your designer have?  Are they a true designer (no JS/jQuery/etc knowledge.. they live & breath PSDs) or are they a designer/front end engineer (they know js/jQuery, the diff. between IE7 and IE9 from a rendering pov).

If you've got a true designer then the best thing to get would be HTML.  A PSD would be okay as well but if they can convert their design into HTML they've done a lot of the hard work for you (unless you love figuring out floats and margins and all that jazz).  That said if you're using something like Twitter Bootstrap or Blueprint CSS then they would obviously have to know how to use that as well.

If you're lucky enough to have a designer/front end engineer then it's well worth your time to teach them some basic razor synax like @Url.Action and @Html.BeginForm.  They can tell you the actions they need and you can work together by giving them a fake data/response version first which they can use while you create a real version.  And in this case they can either use Visual Studio OR you can set it up so that they have your site hosted via IIS on their machine and they just use your source control to get latest which automatically gets placed in the right directory.  Then they can just continue working in whatever editor they prefer as they should only be working in html which will get updated live.  That said if you're using ASP.Net MVC 4 bundling you'll have to decide how to maintain bundles.